# How do I overload notation without getting warnings and not using type classes?

Tags: locale, overloading, typeclass, notation, isabelle

First, without knowing much about type classes, it appears that type classes are the best way to overload notation for a type, unless I can't use type classes, or haven't figured out how. I'm not using type classes.

Second, I'm pretty sure that I don't want to override notation for operators that have meaning for all types, such as `\<in>`, `\<times>`, `*`, `\<union>`, etc.

However, an operator such as `+` has no meaning for my type `sT`, though this ties back into my first point. I eventually would like `+` to have multiple meanings for type `sT => sT => sT`, which, I would think, is not going to happen.

### Four versions of an example

To make my question specific and show that I'm not the only one with the problem, I take a simple example from [Klein's course](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~kleing/teaching/thprv-04/index.html), the file being [Demo14.thy](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~kleing/teaching/thprv-04/slides/Demo14.thy).

After four versions of the example, I ask, "For the fourth example, can I get rid of the warnings?"

He starts with a simple example which gives no warnings or errors:

```
locale semi =
  fixes prod :: "['a, 'a] => 'a" (infixl "\<cdot>" 70)
  assumes assoc: "(x \<cdot> y) \<cdot> z = x \<cdot> (y \<cdot> z)"
```

He uses `\<cdot>`, and this represents what I've been doing so far, not using notation that has already been claimed by Isabelle/HOL.

I change his `\<cdot>` to `+`, and I get an error:

```
locale semi2 =
  fixes prod :: "['a, 'a] => 'a" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
```

Having looked at the HOL sources, I've seen that `+` has been defined for type `('a => 'a => 'a)`, in particular, for certain type classes.

I modify `semi2` to make sure it's not specific to `'a` alone, and I then only get warnings:

```
locale semi3 =
  fixes prod :: "('a => 'a) => ('a => 'a) => 'a" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
```

What I really care about is this fourth version, which gives a warning, even though I've inserted `(x::sT)`:

```
locale semi4 =
  fixes prod :: "sT => sT => sT" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "((x::sT) + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
```

The warning is:

```
Ambiguous input
produces 16 parse trees (10 displayed):
[...]
Fortunately, only one parse tree is type correct,
but you may still want to disambiguate your grammar or your input.
```

### Summary and question

For myself, I summarize it like this: The operator `+` has been defined in many places, and in particular for type `'a => 'a => 'a`, which also in general defines it for `sT => sT => sT`. Because of that, the prover does a lot of work, and after finally figuring out that my `semi4` is the only place that `+` has been defined for type `sT => sT => sT`, it lets me use it.

I don't know about my summary, but can I fix `semi4` so that it doesn't give me a warning?

(Note: Given the example, mathematically it would make more sense to use the symbol `*` instead of `+`, but `*` would be notation that I wouldn't want to override.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured most of it out.

Suppose you have a function

```
myFun :: "myT => myT => myT",
```

and you want to use the plus symbol `+` as notation.

The key is the context in which `+` is defined. At the global level, there are at least two ways. One is the simple way

```
myFun (infixl "+" 70)
```

Another way is defining `+` in a type class definition. In particular, in [Groups.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Groups.html), at line 136 are the two lines

```
class plus =
  fixes plus :: "'a \<Rightarrow> 'a \<Rightarrow> 'a"  (infixl "+" 65)
```

So, with that preface, the short answer is that at the global level, there's only one way to get rid of the warnings when trying to use `+` for `myFun :: "myT => myT => myT"`, and that is to instantiate type `myT` as type class `plus` for the function `myFun`.

Doing that is very simple, where I will show how to do it, and it's independent of all the locales and additional classes in Groups.thy that use `plus`.

However, after defining type `myT` at the global level, whether through the simple way or through type classes, trying to define `+` again for type `(myT => myT => myT)` will cause an error both at the global level, and in locales.

It makes sense now. The use of overloaded syntax is all based on type inference, so a specific syntax for a specific type can only be assigned to one function.

For locales, the use of `+` in different locales is independent. The cause of the warnings is because of the type class definition `plus`. You can't get rid of the warning for locales because `plus` has been defined as a type class for `('a => 'a => 'a)`, which is a global definition.

Here's some code with some comments in it. Instantiating `plus` for `myT` takes all of 5 lines.

```
  typedecl myT

--"Two locales can both use '+'. The warning is because '+' has been defined
   in a type class for 'a. If anything defines '+' globally for type myT, these
   locales will give an error for trying to use it."
locale semi1 =
  fixes plus :: "myT => myT => myT" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "((x::myT) + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
locale semi2 =
  fixes plus :: "myT => myT => myT" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "((x::myT) + y) + z = x + (y + z)"


--"DEFINING PLUS HERE GLOBALLY FOR (myT => myT => myT) RESERVES IT EXCLUSIVELY"

definition myFun :: "myT => myT => myT" (infixl "+" 70) where
  "myFun x y = x"
--"Use of 'value' will give a warning if '+' is instantiated globablly prior
   to this point."
value "(x::myT) + y"


--"PLUS HAS BEEN DEFINED ALREADY. SWITCH THIS NEXT SECTION WITH THAT ABOVE AND
    myFun THEN GETS THE ERROR. DELETE myFun AND THE ERROR GOES AWAY."

definition myT_plus_f :: "myT => myT => myT" where
  "myT_plus_f x y = x"

instantiation myT :: plus
begin
  definition plus_myT:
    "x + y = myT_plus_f x y"  --"Error here if '+' globally defined prior to this for type myT."
  instance ..
end
--"No warning here if '+' instantiated for myT; error if '+' defined globablly for
   type myT."
value "(x::myT) + y"


--"ERRORS HERE FOR LOCALES BECAUSE '+' IS DEFINED GLOBALLY"

locale semi3 =
  fixes plus :: "sT => sT => sT" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "((x::sT) + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
locale semi4 =
  fixes plus :: "sT => sT => sT" (infixl "+" 70)
  assumes assoc: "((x::sT) + y) + z = x + (y + z)"
```